# Pyspak - calculate median value with a sliding time window

Tags: python, pyspark, aggregate, spark-window-function

I have the following data frame in pyspark:

| date | user_country | account_type | num_listens |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-01 | UK | premium | 32 |
| 2022-08-01 | DE | free | 64 |
| 2022-08-01 | FR | free | 93 |
| 2022-08-01 | UK | free | 51 |
| 2022-08-02 | UK | premium | 26 |
| 2022-08-02 | FR | free | 34 |
| 2022-08-02 | DE | free | 29 |
| 2022-08-02 | DE | premium | 41 |
| 2022-08-02 | DE | free | 12 |
| 2022-08-02 | FR | premium | 31 |
| 2022-08-03 | FR | free | 55 |
| 2022-08-03 | UK | premium | 38 |
| 2022-08-03 | UK | premium | 51 |
| 2022-08-03 | FR | free | 81 |
| 2022-08-04 | DE | free | 6 |
| 2022-08-04 | UK | premium | 97 |
| 2022-08-04 | FR | free | 33 |
| 2022-08-04 | UK | premium | 41 |
| 2022-08-04 | FR | premium | 67 |
| 2022-08-04 | DE | free | 86 |
| 2022-08-04 | DE | free | 25 |
| 2022-08-04 | FR | free | 16 |
| 2022-08-04 | FR | free | 48 |
| 2022-08-04 | UK | premium | 11 |
| 2022-08-04 | UK | free | 24 |
| 2022-08-05 | DE | free | 95 |
| 2022-08-05 | FR | free | 68 |
| 2022-08-05 | DE | premium | 23 |
| 2022-08-05 | UK | free | 79 |
| 2022-08-05 | UK | free | 41 |
| 2022-08-05 | DE | premium | 99 |

```
columns = ["date", "user_country","account_type", "num_listens"]
data = [("2022-08-01", "UK", "premium", "32"),
        ("2022-08-01", "DE", "free", "64"),
        ("2022-08-01", "FR", "free", "93"),
        ("2022-08-01", "UK", "free", "51"),
        ("2022-08-02", "UK", "premium", "26"),
        ("2022-08-02", "FR", "free", "34"),
        ("2022-08-02", "DE", "free", "29"),
        ("2022-08-02", "DE", "premium", "41"),
        ("2022-08-02", "DE", "free", "12"),
        ("2022-08-02", "FR", "premium", "31"),
        ("2022-08-03", "FR", "free", "55"),
        ("2022-08-03", "UK", "premium", "38"),
        ("2022-08-03", "UK", "premium", "51"),
        ("2022-08-03", "FR", "free", "81"),
        ("2022-08-04", "DE", "free", "6"),
        ("2022-08-04", "UK", "premium", "97"),
        ("2022-08-04", "FR", "free", "33"),
        ("2022-08-04", "UK", "premium", "41"),
        ("2022-08-04", "FR", "premium", "67"),
        ("2022-08-04", "DE", "free", "86"),
        ("2022-08-04", "DE", "free", "25"),
        ("2022-08-04", "FR", "free", "16"),
        ("2022-08-04", "FR", "free", "48"),
        ("2022-08-04", "UK", "premium", "11"),
        ("2022-08-04", "UK", "free", "24"),
        ("2022-08-05", "DE", "free", "95"),
        ("2022-08-05", "FR", "free", "68"),
        ("2022-08-05", "DE", "premium", "23"),
        ("2022-08-05", "UK", "free", "79"),
        ("2022-08-05", "UK", "free", "41"),
        ("2022-08-05", "DE", "premium", "99")        
       ]
```

I'm trying to group this data by user_country, account_type and num_listens, always calculating the median value for each group. On top of this I would like to use a sliding time window to restrict the data I use for each aggregation. For example, when calculating the median value on 2022-08-04, I would only like to use data from the ten dates prior.

The resulting table should look as follows:

| snapshot_date | user_country | account_type | median |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-06 | UK | premium | 38 |
| 2022-08-06 | DE | free | 29 |
| 2022-08-06 | FR | free | 52 |
| 2022-08-06 | UK | free | 46 |
| 2022-08-06 | DE | premium | 41 |
| 2022-08-06 | FR | premium | 49 |
| 2022-08-05 | UK | premium | 38 |
| 2022-08-05 | DE | free | 27 |
| 2022-08-05 | FR | free | 48 |
| 2022-08-05 | UK | free | 38 |
| 2022-08-05 | DE | premium | 41 |
| 2022-08-05 | FR | premium | 49 |
| 2022-08-04 | UK | premium | 35 |
| 2022-08-04 | DE | free | 29 |
| 2022-08-04 | FR | free | 68 |
| 2022-08-04 | UK | free | 51 |
| 2022-08-04 | DE | premium | 41 |
| 2022-08-04 | FR | premium | 31 |
| 2022-08-03 | UK | premium | 29 |
| 2022-08-03 | DE | free | 29 |
| 2022-08-03 | FR | free | 64 |
| 2022-08-03 | UK | free | 51 |
| 2022-08-03 | DE | premium | 41 |
| 2022-08-03 | FR | premium | 31 |
| 2022-08-02 | UK | premium | 32 |
| 2022-08-02 | DE | free | 64 |
| 2022-08-02 | FR | free | 93 |
| 2022-08-02 | UK | free | 51 |

The value in the first row would be the median number of listens for all UK users with the premium account, using data from the previous 10 days (I only included a small sample of 5 days so in this specific case there would not be the full desired rang of 10 days available).

Any help on how this can be achieved in pyspark would be much appreciated. I've been fiddling around with combining a group by with a window function but have been unable to get the desired result.

Comment: fyi - your input and expected output don't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the values in an array, and then apply the median logic on that.

For simplicity, I'll calculate the median of a window of 4 dates using your sample data. This is considering you don't want a continuity in the dates, i.e. previous 3 dates may or may not be in sequence (`[2022-01-01, 2022-01-03, 2022-01-04, 2022-01-04]` is also acceptable).

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('num_listens_arr', 
               func.array_sort(func.collect_list('num_listens').
                               over(wd.partitionBy('user_country', 'account_type').orderBy('date').rowsBetween(-3, 0))
                               )
               ). \
    withColumn('median', 
               func.when(func.size('num_listens_arr') % 2 == 0, 
                         func.expr('(num_listens_arr[int(size(num_listens_arr) / 2)-1] + num_listens_arr[int(size(num_listens_arr) / 2)]) / 2').cast('double')
                         ).
               otherwise(func.expr('num_listens_arr[int(size(num_listens_arr) / 2)]').cast('double'))
               ). \
    show(data_sdf.count())

# +----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+------+
# |      date|user_country|account_type|num_listens| num_listens_arr|median|
# +----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+------+
# |2022-08-01|          UK|        free|         51|            [51]|  51.0|
# |2022-08-04|          UK|        free|         24|        [24, 51]|  37.5|
# |2022-08-05|          UK|        free|         79|    [24, 51, 79]|  51.0|
# |2022-08-05|          UK|        free|         41|[24, 41, 51, 79]|  46.0|
# |2022-08-01|          UK|     premium|         32|            [32]|  32.0|
# |2022-08-02|          UK|     premium|         26|        [26, 32]|  29.0|
# |2022-08-03|          UK|     premium|         38|    [26, 32, 38]|  32.0|
# |2022-08-03|          UK|     premium|         51|[26, 32, 38, 51]|  35.0|
# |2022-08-04|          UK|     premium|         97|[26, 38, 51, 97]|  44.5|
# |2022-08-04|          UK|     premium|         41|[38, 41, 51, 97]|  46.0|
# |2022-08-04|          UK|     premium|         11|[11, 41, 51, 97]|  46.0|
# |2022-08-02|          DE|     premium|         41|            [41]|  41.0|
# |2022-08-05|          DE|     premium|         23|        [23, 41]|  32.0|
# |2022-08-05|          DE|     premium|         99|    [23, 41, 99]|  41.0|
# |2022-08-01|          DE|        free|         64|            [64]|  64.0|
# |2022-08-02|          DE|        free|         29|        [29, 64]|  46.5|
# |2022-08-02|          DE|        free|         12|    [12, 29, 64]|  29.0|
# |2022-08-04|          DE|        free|          6| [6, 12, 29, 64]|  20.5|
# |2022-08-04|          DE|        free|         86| [6, 12, 29, 86]|  20.5|
# |2022-08-04|          DE|        free|         25| [6, 12, 25, 86]|  18.5|
# |2022-08-05|          DE|        free|         95| [6, 25, 86, 95]|  55.5|
# |2022-08-01|          FR|        free|         93|            [93]|  93.0|
# |2022-08-02|          FR|        free|         34|        [34, 93]|  63.5|
# |2022-08-03|          FR|        free|         55|    [34, 55, 93]|  55.0|
# |2022-08-03|          FR|        free|         81|[34, 55, 81, 93]|  68.0|
# |2022-08-04|          FR|        free|         33|[33, 34, 55, 81]|  44.5|
# |2022-08-04|          FR|        free|         16|[16, 33, 55, 81]|  44.0|
# |2022-08-04|          FR|        free|         48|[16, 33, 48, 81]|  40.5|
# |2022-08-05|          FR|        free|         68|[16, 33, 48, 68]|  40.5|
# |2022-08-02|          FR|     premium|         31|            [31]|  31.0|
# |2022-08-04|          FR|     premium|         67|        [31, 67]|  49.0|
# +----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+------+
```

If you do want to maintain the sequence of dates, you can use a `rangeBetween()`.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('dt_long', func.col('date').cast('timestamp').cast('long')). \
    withColumn('num_listens_arr', 
               func.array_sort(func.collect_list('num_listens').
                               over(wd.partitionBy('user_country', 'account_type').orderBy('dt_long').rangeBetween(-3*24*60*60, 0))
                               )
               ). \
    withColumn('median', 
               func.when(func.size('num_listens_arr') % 2 == 0, 
                         func.expr('(num_listens_arr[int(size(num_listens_arr) / 2)-1] + num_listens_arr[int(size(num_listens_arr) / 2)]) / 2').cast('double')
                         ).
               otherwise(func.expr('num_listens_arr[int(size(num_listens_arr) / 2)]').cast('double'))
               ). \
    show(data_sdf.count(), truncate=False)

# +----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+------+
# |date      |user_country|account_type|num_listens|dt_long   |num_listens_arr             |median|
# +----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+------+
# |2022-08-01|UK          |free        |51         |1659312000|[51]                        |51.0  |
# |2022-08-04|UK          |free        |24         |1659571200|[24, 51]                    |37.5  |
# |2022-08-05|UK          |free        |79         |1659657600|[24, 41, 79]                |41.0  |
# |2022-08-05|UK          |free        |41         |1659657600|[24, 41, 79]                |41.0  |
# |2022-08-01|UK          |premium     |32         |1659312000|[32]                        |32.0  |
# |2022-08-02|UK          |premium     |26         |1659398400|[26, 32]                    |29.0  |
# |2022-08-03|UK          |premium     |38         |1659484800|[26, 32, 38, 51]            |35.0  |
# |2022-08-03|UK          |premium     |51         |1659484800|[26, 32, 38, 51]            |35.0  |
# |2022-08-04|UK          |premium     |97         |1659571200|[11, 26, 32, 38, 41, 51, 97]|38.0  |
# |2022-08-04|UK          |premium     |41         |1659571200|[11, 26, 32, 38, 41, 51, 97]|38.0  |
# |2022-08-04|UK          |premium     |11         |1659571200|[11, 26, 32, 38, 41, 51, 97]|38.0  |
# |2022-08-02|DE          |premium     |41         |1659398400|[41]                        |41.0  |
# |2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |23         |1659657600|[23, 41, 99]                |41.0  |
# |2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |99         |1659657600|[23, 41, 99]                |41.0  |
# |2022-08-01|DE          |free        |64         |1659312000|[64]                        |64.0  |
# |2022-08-02|DE          |free        |29         |1659398400|[12, 29, 64]                |29.0  |
# |2022-08-02|DE          |free        |12         |1659398400|[12, 29, 64]                |29.0  |
# |2022-08-04|DE          |free        |6          |1659571200|[6, 12, 25, 29, 64, 86]     |27.0  |
# |2022-08-04|DE          |free        |86         |1659571200|[6, 12, 25, 29, 64, 86]     |27.0  |
# |2022-08-04|DE          |free        |25         |1659571200|[6, 12, 25, 29, 64, 86]     |27.0  |
# |2022-08-05|DE          |free        |95         |1659657600|[6, 12, 25, 29, 86, 95]     |27.0  |
# |2022-08-01|FR          |free        |93         |1659312000|[93]                        |93.0  |
# |2022-08-02|FR          |free        |34         |1659398400|[34, 93]                    |63.5  |
# |2022-08-03|FR          |free        |55         |1659484800|[34, 55, 81, 93]            |68.0  |
# |2022-08-03|FR          |free        |81         |1659484800|[34, 55, 81, 93]            |68.0  |
# |2022-08-04|FR          |free        |33         |1659571200|[16, 33, 34, 48, 55, 81, 93]|48.0  |
# |2022-08-04|FR          |free        |16         |1659571200|[16, 33, 34, 48, 55, 81, 93]|48.0  |
# |2022-08-04|FR          |free        |48         |1659571200|[16, 33, 34, 48, 55, 81, 93]|48.0  |
# |2022-08-05|FR          |free        |68         |1659657600|[16, 33, 34, 48, 55, 68, 81]|48.0  |
# |2022-08-02|FR          |premium     |31         |1659398400|[31]                        |31.0  |
# |2022-08-04|FR          |premium     |67         |1659571200|[31, 67]                    |49.0  |
# +----------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------+------+
```

Coming to the median calculation, if the array of the values has even number of elements, the average of the middle 2 elements should be the resulting median.

- so, sort the array of values
- check the `size` of the array (number of elements)

  - if the number of elements in the array is divisible by 2, calculate average of `(size/2)-1`<sup>th</sup> and `(size/2)`<sup>th</sup> elements - e.g., if size is 6, `arr[2]` element and `arr[3]` element
  - otherwise, just take the middle value as median

Answer (score 1):

As there are some missing records in some date in your dataframe (eg 2022-08-03 - DE - free), but you still need to calculate the median of these records. Therefore, I will create a reference table to store all the combination first:

```
ref_tbl = df\
    .groupBy('user_country', 'account_type')\
    .agg(func.sequence(func.min(func.to_date('date')), func.max(func.to_date('date'))).alias('date_lst'))
ref_tbl = ref_tbl\
    .select(
        func.explode('date_lst').alias('date'),
        'user_country', 'account_type',
        func.lit(0).alias('num_listens')
    )\
    .withColumn('date', func.date_format('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

ref_tbl.show(20, False)
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
|date      |user_country|account_type|num_listens|
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
|2022-08-01|UK          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-02|UK          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-03|UK          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-04|UK          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-01|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-02|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-03|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-05|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-01|FR          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-02|FR          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-03|FR          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-04|FR          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-05|FR          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-01|UK          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-02|UK          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-03|UK          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-04|UK          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-05|UK          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-02|DE          |premium     |0          |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

Then we can union this reference table back to the main dataframe:

```
df2 = df\
    .unionByName(ref_tbl)\
    .orderBy(['user_country', 'account_type', 'date'])
df2.show(20, False)
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
|date      |user_country|account_type|num_listens|
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
|2022-08-01|DE          |free        |64         |
|2022-08-01|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-02|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-02|DE          |free        |12         |
|2022-08-02|DE          |free        |29         |
|2022-08-03|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |86         |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |25         |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |6          |
|2022-08-05|DE          |free        |0          |
|2022-08-05|DE          |free        |95         |
|2022-08-02|DE          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-02|DE          |premium     |41         |
|2022-08-03|DE          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-04|DE          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |0          |
|2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |23         |
|2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |99         |
|2022-08-01|FR          |free        |93         |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

You question is to collect the the previous 10 day of the records and calculate the median, in fact it equals to take today and previous 9 day of records. You can use a window function to achieve this goal:

```
window_func = Window\
    .partitionBy('user_country', 'account_type')\
    .orderBy(func.expr("unix_date(to_date(date))"))\
    .rangeBetween(-9, 0)

df3 = df2\
    .select(
        'date', 'user_country', 'account_type',
        func.collect_list(func.when(func.col('num_listens')>0, func.col('num_listens')).otherwise(func.lit(None))).over(window_func).alias('value_lst')
    ).distinct()\
    .orderBy(['date', 'user_country', 'account_type'], ascending=[0, 0, 0])

df3.show(10, False)
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------------+
|date      |user_country|account_type|value_lst                       |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------------+
|2022-08-05|UK          |free        |[51, 24, 79, 41]                |
|2022-08-05|FR          |free        |[93, 34, 55, 81, 33, 16, 48, 68]|
|2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |[41, 23, 99]                    |
|2022-08-05|DE          |free        |[64, 29, 12, 6, 86, 25, 95]     |
|2022-08-04|UK          |premium     |[32, 26, 38, 51, 97, 41, 11]    |
|2022-08-04|UK          |free        |[51, 24]                        |
|2022-08-04|FR          |premium     |[31, 67]                        |
|2022-08-04|FR          |free        |[93, 34, 55, 81, 33, 16, 48]    |
|2022-08-04|DE          |premium     |[41]                            |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |[64, 29, 12, 6, 86, 25]         |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

Finally you can calculate the median:

```
import statistics

df4 = df3\
    .withColumn('median', func.udf(lambda lst: statistics.median([int(value) for value in lst]))(func.col('value_lst')))

df4.show(10, False)
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------------+------+
|date      |user_country|account_type|value_lst                       |median|
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------------+------+
|2022-08-05|UK          |free        |[51, 24, 79, 41]                |46.0  |
|2022-08-05|FR          |free        |[93, 34, 55, 81, 33, 16, 48, 68]|51.5  |
|2022-08-05|DE          |premium     |[41, 23, 99]                    |41    |
|2022-08-05|DE          |free        |[64, 29, 12, 6, 86, 25, 95]     |29    |
|2022-08-04|UK          |premium     |[32, 26, 38, 51, 97, 41, 11]    |38    |
|2022-08-04|UK          |free        |[51, 24]                        |37.5  |
|2022-08-04|FR          |premium     |[31, 67]                        |49.0  |
|2022-08-04|FR          |free        |[93, 34, 55, 81, 33, 16, 48]    |48    |
|2022-08-04|DE          |premium     |[41]                            |41    |
|2022-08-04|DE          |free        |[64, 29, 12, 6, 86, 25]         |27.0  |
+----------+------------+------------+--------------------------------+------+
only showing top 10 rows
```

The reason why I don't use the `percentile` or `approxQuantile` in Spark API here is because they are all approximation but not exact (for example if the list is `[1, 2]`, spark `percentile` will take `1` as median but not `1.5`). Therefore you need to use the UDF with external library / create your own logic to achieve your goal, but please remember the performance might be bad if the list is too large.