# Pyspark - Can I add condition to specify what date range to perform aggregation with Window Function?

Tags: pyspark

Let's say today is 20221031.
Data is like follows:

| create_time | id | type | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20221031 | 1 | A | 10 |
| 20221030 | 1 | A | 10 |
| 20221031 | 2 | A | 10 |
| 20221030 | 2 | B | 10 |
| 20220928 | 1 | A | 10 |

What I want:

| create_time | id | type | amount | sum_amount_within_one_month | sum_amount_within_three_months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20221031 | 1 | A | 10 | 20(there are two records where id=1 and type=A within one month) | 30(there are three records where id=1 and type=A within 3 months) |
| 20221030 | 1 | A | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 20221031 | 2 | A | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 20221030 | 2 | B | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 20220928 | 1 | A | 10 | 20 | 30 |

What I have tried:

```
df.withColumn("sum_amount_within_one_month", F.sum("amount").over(Window.partitionBy("id","type").where(df.create_date > "20220930")))
```

This fails with an error:
WindowSpec object has no attribute 'where'

Comment: you might be able to use `rangeBetween` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73865423/8279585)

Comment: lets say there are 4 records, of the same id/type, of 4 consecutive months (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4) - how does the sum look like for the months?